# Write metadata on a PDF generated by Adobe LiveCycle

Tags: adobe, pdf-generation, livecycle

I'm writing a template XDP and my need is to set some custom metadata into the generated PDF.

Metadata should be set by an embedded script (Javascript) set to run on client side (in my tests, I've tried to run the script on the Server side too, but nothing changed).

I've tried these solutions (this code is in the "initialize" section of the page of my XDP template):

```
var oNode=xfa.form.createNode("text", "test1");
this.desc.nodes.append(oNode);
oNode.value = "OK";
```

---

```
setProperty(xfa.form, "test2", "OK");
setProperty(this.desc, "test3", "OK");
setProperty(xfa.xmpmeta, "test4", "OK");

function setProperty(node, property, value)
{
    var item = node.desc.nodes.namedItem(property);
    if (item == null)
    {
     // if the specified property does not exist then create it
     var item = xfa.form.createNode('text', property);
     node.desc.nodes.append(item);
    }
    item.value = value;
    return;
}
```

---

```
updateMetaData("creator", "TEST5 OK");
updateMetaData("test6", "OK");

function updateMetaData(vName, vValue)
{
    var vDesc = xfa.template.["#subform"].desc;
    if (vDesc.nodes.namedItem(vName) == null)
    {
        vDesc.nodes.append(xfa.template.createNode("text", vName));
        vDesc[vName].value = vValue;
    }
}
```

When I take the PDF generated by the above code, everytime the PDF metadata weren't set, please someone can help me to understand what is wrong or give me a working solution?

Thanks in advance